# SQL Server Log Shipping: Does the native log shipping support encryption of the tlog backup?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

SQL Server 2014 Std Edition

We use the built in SQL Server encryption for our db backups (sql server backup to disk) -- works great.

We would like to implement encryption for the tlog backups (which fire every 3 min)

Is this possible? Will the built in log shipping feature magically make it all happen?

We do not want to use redgate or third party tools.

Please advise how to solve, if the built in log shipping feature does not solve.

Comment: What tool are you using to encrypt your backups ? We use redgate and it has ability to encrypt log backups as well.

Comment: @Kin Fair call. OP enhanced.

Comment: I guess that would be possible but you have to prepare a TSQL version of logshipping and in that whenever a log backup files you have to include keyword encryption.

Comment: @Shanky Thanks! Note that this thread concerns the _native_ log shipping feature in SQL Server.... the wizard driven, it does the magic log shipping.

Comment: I dont think you have option to specify backup with encryption in LS GUI